# DirectoryNotFoundException when creating a BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, bitmapimage

I develop an IOC framework in the form of a DLL that creates the application's main window and displays various WPF Pages in it.  There is a folder of PNG images with their Build Action set to Resource.  I use code like this to set the sources of WPF Image elements...

```
MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyAssembly;component/Images/MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

This works great.  However, there is also a feature where the user can choose to display one of these WPF Pages in a separate window.  Here is the mystery:  If the user navigates to the page in the main window before showing it in a separate window, all is well.  However, if the user shows the page in a separate window before it is shown in the main window, I get a `DirectoryNotFoundException` saying " Could not find a part of the path 'C:\MyAssembly;component\Images\MyImage.png'."

I discovered the OnLoad cache option and tried the following code...

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.UriSource = new Uri("/MyAssembly;component/Images/MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
image.EndInit();
MyImage.Source = image;
```

However, I then get the `DirectoryNotFoundException` on the very first image that I attempt to create.

I also tried an absolute URI...

```
MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Images/MyImage.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

I then get a `UriFormatException` saying "Invalid URI: Invalid port specified."

Comment: Thanks for the update. You should put that as an official answer to the question.

Comment: I intend to.  Stack Overflow says that I have to wait 8 hours because I'm a new member.

Comment: Ahh right. Welcome! Good to have another person who writes clear questions on here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the 'pack' URI format as shown in the question.  However, I needed to make a call to the Application class before I did so.  This has the effect of executing the Application's static constructor which registers the 'pack' URI scheme.  I found my answer [here](http://compilewith.net/2009/03/wpf-unit-testing-trouble-with-pack-uris.html).  The call I used was simply this:

```
var app = Application.Current;
```